# Combine 2 WP_queries into one (OR relation)

Tags: wp-query

I have 2 WP_queries that I want to combine into 1 query. These are my orginal 2 queries:

```
$childlist = new WP_Query( array (
    'numberposts'   => -1,
    'post_type'     => 'page',
    'post_parent'   => $post->ID,
    'fields'        => 'ids'
));
$childlist2 = new WP_Query( array (
    'numberposts'   => -1,
    'post_type'     => 'page',
    'meta_key'      => 'extra_menu',
    'meta_value'    => $post->ID,
    'meta_compare'  => 'LIKE',
    'fields'        => 'ids'
));
```

I tried combining them in several differten ways, but I can't seem to find a working solution. As soon as I try this OR relation it will only give results for the second part in the "OR".

```
$childlist = new WP_Query(array(
    'numberposts'   => -1,
    'post_type'     => 'page',
    'meta_query'    =>  array(
        'relation'      => 'OR',
            array(
                'key' => 'post_parent',
                'value' => $post->ID,
                'compare' => '=',
            ),
            array(
                'key'       => 'extra_menu',
                'value'     => $post->ID,
                'compare'   => 'LIKE',
            ),
        ),
));
```

Any thoughts on how I can fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`meta_query` can only be used for meta queries, you can't use it for non-meta parameters. Even if you could, it would not give a performance benefit.

What you want can't be done, and your second example is searching for posts that have a post meta named `post_parent`.

The canonical answer, is to use 2 query objects and 2 loops, or, to use a common method of indicating parent/child relationships so that only 1 query is necessary.

Additionally:

- Using `-1` to fetch all posts is dangerous, never do this. This is a great way to introduce memory exhaustion problems as the site grows larger

  - *"But I only have 50 posts it should never get that far"* then ask for 60 posts and guarantee that it never will. A high value is always preferable to unlimited value. If you need to show all of them, then infinite scrolling and pagination are far better options.
- By asking only for the IDs, you might think you are improving performance, but instead you are hurting it. WP will fetch all the post data in one query to speed things up, but now it has to do a query every, single, time to fetch individual post objects. So rather than 1 query to fetch 300 posts all at once, you now have 300 queries to fetch individual posts. Anytime you ask for the title, or post meta, grab the posts permalink, etc
- Querying for posts by their post meta values is super expensive, and gets more expensive as the site grows larger. This is what taxonomies are for, use a taxonomy. Think about it, why did they store post tags and categories in a taxonomy table instead of using post meta? Because it's slow! Post meta tables are optimised for finding values when you already know the post ID. Taxonomy tables are optimised for finding post IDs when you know the value

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. What I'm trying to accomplish is placing a page (not a post) on 2 different places in our menu. The menu is build by parent -> child relation. So I've created a custom field to make it possible to add an extra relation. There are only a few pages on the whole site that need multiple parents.

Comment: pages are posts of type `page`, there is no meaningful difference at the database layer or `WP_Query`. Querying for 50 posts of type `post` is the same as querying for 50 posts of type `page`

Comment: Also, if you only have a single post with that post meta, the query still gets more expensive as the site increases in size, the database has to do a full table search of the post meta table, and can't rely on indexes to speed things up, it's a worst scenario everytime.

Comment: It would be significantly faster to instead store a post meta with a list of child post IDs, then you could use `get_post_meta` which is orders of magnitude faster, so much so that WP will have pre-fetched it into memory via `WP_Query` (something that won't happen if you set `'fields'        => 'ids'` though)

Comment: can I in the same way store a post meta with a list of child parent IDs?

Comment: If you are suggesting what I think you're suggesting, just know that storing a post meta that contains the parent ID defeats the point and will involve a very big cost, and poor practice. IMO duplicating pages would be both cheaper and preferable. It is a very bad idea, and completely unnecessary (I already suggested an alternative that in some situations is _thousands_ of times faster in my last comment). Are you trying to avoid my last proposal because you aren't sure how to implement it?

Comment: TLDR: Store a pages children, not a pages parent, its faster and easier, and completely eliminates one of your queries

Comment: I was indeed trying to avoid your proposal. Not because I'm not sure how to implement it, but for the reason that with your suggestion you need to edit 2 pages when creating a new page. First create the new page itself, and then you need to edit the parent page to add this new child. That last step might be forgotten by the content creators. I understand there is a huge performance profit doing it that way, so I guess that's the only correct way to implement it. Using ('fields' => 'ids') was just for testing purposes. This won't be added in the final code!

Comment: Ah that's just a UX issue. E.g. if i have a dropdown to select a parent post, I don't have to store the result of that dropdown on the current post, e.g. `add_post_meta( $parent_post_id, 'show_in_child_menu', $current_post_id )`. You can store 2 post meta and use one of them just for the edit post UI so you can avoid another `meta_query`. You could even register a private taxonomy where the term names are the parent post id, but I don't know that you really need that ( it too would have better performance, hidden taxonomies ftw )

Comment: Got it! Thanks a lot for your patience... I think I have a clue now how I can implement it.